# SQL Server 2008 - Union of 4 queries and ordering by relevance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm facing an issue that my query cannot order by relevance since I declared 'column' MATCH and try to ordering by it.

I'm trying to create a stored procedure using `UNION`.

This query has some rules that I need to follow since I need to bring 3 related articles. Each rule has a query that I tried to unite them.

Let me explain those rules:

1. I need to search and match and article that has the same TAG related to it inside the same project (as `CampanhaId`)
2. I need to search and match the same TAG without be inside the same project, but public articles
3. Recent articles at the same project
4. Recent public article

I need to follow these rules in priory and search for first three articles passing by then.

So, if first rule hasn't at least 3 articles, the second rule will try to fill it. The third and fourth rules follow the same way.

I tried to create a query like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetNoticiaRelacionada]
    (@Tag VARCHAR(50), @ExtranetId INT, @CampanhaAreaId INT, @NoticiaId INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 3 * 
    FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT 
            ArtigoId, CategoriaId, Titulo, Conteudo, 
            Subtitulo, Categoria, FotoCompacta, QtdResposta,
            0 AS MATCH, DataAlteracao 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
                 A.ArtigoId, A.CategoriaId, A.Titulo, A.Conteudo,
                 A.Subtitulo, C.Nome AS Categoria, 
                 A.ImgAlt AS FotoCompacta,
                 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comentario C 
                  WHERE C.GenericAreaId = A.ArtigoId) AS QtdResposta,
                 1 AS MATCH, A.DataAlteracao
             FROM 
                 Artigo A
             JOIN 
                 ArtigoCategoria C ON A.CategoriaId = C.CategoriaId
             WHERE 
                 A.Apagado = 0 
                 AND A.TAG COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI LIKE '%' + @Tag + '%' 
                 AND A.CampanhaAreaId = @CampanhaAreaId 
                 AND A.ArtigoId <> @NoticiaId

       UNION

SELECT A.ArtigoId
,A.CategoriaId
,A.Titulo
,A.Conteudo
,A.Subtitulo
,C.Nome AS Categoria
,A.ImgAlt AS FotoCompacta
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comentario C WHERE C.GenericAreaId = A.ArtigoId) AS QtdResposta
,2 AS MATCH
,A.DataAlteracao
FROM Artigo A
JOIN ArtigoCategoria C ON A.CategoriaId = C.CategoriaId
WHERE A.Apagado = 0 AND A.TAG COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI LIKE '%' + @Tag + '%' AND A.CampanhaId = @ExtranetId AND A.ArtigoId <> @NoticiaId

UNION

SELECT A.ArtigoId
,A.CategoriaId
,A.Titulo
,A.Conteudo
,A.Subtitulo
,C.Nome AS Categoria
,A.ImgAlt AS FotoCompacta
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comentario C WHERE C.GenericAreaId = A.ArtigoId) AS QtdResposta
,3 AS MATCH
,A.DataAlteracao
FROM Artigo A
JOIN ArtigoCategoria C ON A.CategoriaId = C.CategoriaId
WHERE A.Apagado = 0 AND A.CampanhaAreaId = @CampanhaAreaId AND A.ArtigoId <> @NoticiaId

UNION

SELECT A.ArtigoId
,A.CategoriaId
,A.Titulo
,A.Conteudo
,A.Subtitulo
,C.Nome AS Categoria
,A.ImgAlt AS FotoCompacta
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comentario C WHERE C.GenericAreaId = A.ArtigoId) AS QtdResposta
,4 AS MATCH
,A.DataAlteracao
FROM Artigo A
JOIN ArtigoCategoria C ON A.CategoriaId = C.CategoriaId
WHERE A.Apagado = 0 AND A.CampanhaId = @ExtranetId AND A.ArtigoId <> @NoticiaId
) AS T
GROUP BY 
ArtigoId
,CategoriaId
,Titulo
,Conteudo
,Subtitulo
,Categoria
,FotoCompacta
,QtdResposta
,MATCH
,DataAlteracao) AS T2

ORDER BY T2.MATCH ASC, T2.DataAlteracao DESC
END
```

So, the first query returns only Articles in the same TAG and Project.

The second one, returns all Articles with matching the same TAG.

The third one, matches all Article in the same Project.

The last one matches all Article published.

My real problem, I guess, all the results don't respect that order.

If I have two articles with the same TAG, this should bring first as related articles, but somehow this brings first any article that I updated recently and should not be the first one in the list.

When I tried to execute this procedure, SQL Server always returns the column `Match` with a value of `0`.

I think the problem is inside this Match column that I cannot order by it.

If someone needs more information, please advise me. I'll be appreciate any help.

I don't have any further actions I need to take.

Comment: Its a SQL Query statement, not pog's programming... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing "SELECT 0 AS MATCH" in your outer query, which means it is over-writing any values in your inner query.

In other words, to expose the issue, your code could be simplified to this:

```
SELECT 0 AS Match
FROM (
 SELECT 1 AS Match
 UNION 
 SELECT 2 AS Match
 UNION 
 SELECT 3 AS Match
 UNION 
 SELECT 4 AS Match
)
ORDER BY Match
```

Since you are using Match 1-4 in the inner query, but then stating "SELECT 0 AS Match" in the outer query that selects from the inner query, all the rows are going to have 0 for Match.

Instead of getting "0 AS Match" in the outer query, you should just get Match from the inner query.

Comment: I got what you said, but if I try to remove "Select 0 AS MATCH", my query statement shows duplicated records. How  can I resolve this other issue? @TabAlleman

Comment: Put it back the way it was, but instead of "0 AS Match", just select "Match", so you get the value from the inner query.

Comment: Incredible. I just did this what you said and it works. Thanks @TabAlleman

Comment: Edited my answer to include this step.   Glad it worked.